# javascript tabs not making first tab active

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am using simple tabs with javascript. Currently the javascript is set If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab. If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab. What I would like is for it to set all the tab content to display none until the tab has been clicked.

```
$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
// For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
// which tab is active and it's associated content
var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

// If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
// If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
$active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
$active.addClass('active');

$content = $($active[0].hash);

// Hide the remaining content
$links.not($active).each(function () {
  $(this.hash).hide();
});

// Bind the click event handler
$(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
  // Make the old tab inactive.
  $active.removeClass('active');
  $content.hide();

  // Update the variables with the new link and content
  $active = $(this);
  $content = $(this.hash);

  // Make the tab active.
  $active.addClass('active');
  $content.show();

  // Prevent the anchor's default click action
  e.preventDefault();
});
 });
```

Comment: After `$content = $($active[0].hash);` put `$content.hide()` to hide every content...

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was missing!